# Capture task from gantt chart in one screen

Tags: microsoft-project, gantt

Hi I have created a Gantt Chart where the tasks are not shown in one screen. To view the rest tasks I have to scroll down. What I am trying is to zoom out the tasks so that I can capture it as a image. But I don't know how to do that. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any good screenshot program such as Snagit, FastStone Capture, HyperSnap and so on supports *scrolling window capture*.

However you might not require an external utility since MS Project (at least [since 2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-help/top-tips-for-project-HA001096334.aspx)) has an in-built **Copy Picture** feature:

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks its working now.. could you please tell me how to hide todays line which is showing red from timescale? I would like to show that the project is completed and it needs to be seen that I have taken screen shot after the completion of project not in the middle of the project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, will have to check it out. I suggest you post a new question preferably with a screenshot highlighting what exactly is to be hidden.

Comment: Actually I did solve it. My latest answer was hidden on your 1st reply. What I need to do in order to print the entire tasks is to select them first and after that if I click on copy picture then I captures the entire tasks.